Audio mixing problem in cpp
I am working on developing a screen recorder application using C++ in Windows. In the application when I enable only output audio (i.e. speakers), the speaker audio is recorded smoothly without noise. Similarly, when I enable only input audio (i.e. microphone), the microphone audio is also recorded smoothly without noise. But when I enable both input and output audio and try to mix those two audio signals, the mixed audio became distorted. It makes it clear that the distortion or noise occurs in the function in which I am mixing those 2 audio signals.
I have stored the input (microphone) audio and output (speaker) audio into 2 separate vectors named std::vector &inputAudio and std::vector &outputAudio respectively. The mixer function takes those two vectors as arguments and returns mixedAudio of type vector.
I have tried to mix the input and output audio in two different approach. In the first approach, I tried to perform mathematical addition of each 8-bit (unsigned char) sample of input and output audio individually and pushed the mixed sample in the mixedAudio vector individually. But this approach adds noise in the mixedAudio.
Then, I came to know that the computer saves audio as 16-bit samples. That’s why, in the second approach, I have tried to perform mathematical addition of each 16-bit (i.e. 2 successive bytes in the vector) sample of input and output audio individually and pushed the mixed 16-bit sample in the mixedAudio vector. This approach removes the noise but the mixedAudio is slightly distorted and the mixed audio seems to break for a fraction of a second after a few seconds every time.
I have provided the code of my two approaches here.
Approach 1(Adding 8 bit sample at each iteration)
    static std::vector<BYTE> MixAudio(std::vector<BYTE> &first, std::vector<BYTE> &second)
    {
        std::vector<BYTE> newvector; //this is the mixedAudio vector
    
        if (first.size() >= second.size())
        {
            // This will overlay both the samples
            newvector.insert(newvector.end(), first.begin(), first.end());
    
            for (int i = 0; i < second.size(); i++)
            {
                newvector[i] += second[i];
        }
        }
        else
        {
            //This will clip the second sample to the length of the first.
            vector<BYTE>::iterator end = first.size() > 0 ? second.begin() += first.size() : second.end();
            newvector.insert(newvector.end(), second.begin(), end);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++)
            {
                newvector[i] += first[i];
        }
        }
    
        return newvector;
    }

Approach 2(Adding 16 bit sample at each iteration)
    static std::vector<BYTE> MixAudio(std::vector<BYTE>& audio1, std::vector<BYTE>& audio2)
    {
        size_t minSize = audio1.size() < audio2.size() ? audio1.size() : audio2.size();
        std::vector<BYTE> result; //this is the mixedAudio vector
    
    
        // Mix the overlapping parts
        for (size_t i = 0; i < minSize; i += 2) {
            // Convert bytes to 16-bit integers
            int32_t sample1 = static_cast<int32_t>((audio1[i]<<8) | audio1[i + 1]);
            int32_t sample2 = static_cast<int32_t>((audio2[i]<<8) | audio2[i + 1]);
    
            // Mix samples and clip to the 16-bit range
            int32_t mixedSample = (sample1) + (sample2);
            if (mixedSample < -32768)
                LOGINFO(L"UNDERFLOWED");
                //if mixedSample is overflowed over 16 bit
            if (mixedSample & 0x10000)
            {
                mixedSample = (mixedSample & 0x0000FFFF) + 1;
            }
            //if (mixedSample > 32767) mixedSample = 32767;
            
    
            // Convert the mixed sample back to bytes
            result.push_back(static_cast<BYTE>((mixedSample >> 8) & 0xFF));
            result.push_back(static_cast<BYTE>(mixedSample & 0xFF));
    
            
        }
    
        // Append remaining samples from the longer vector
        if (audio1.size() > minSize) {
            result.insert(result.end(), audio1.begin() + minSize, audio1.end());
        }
        else if (audio2.size() > minSize) {
            result.insert(result.end(), audio2.begin() + minSize, audio2.end());
        }
    
        return result;

If anyone has experience of working on mixing speaker and microphone audio in cpp, please help me with how I can mix audio without any noise.

Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. In general, as Knut Inge states in their answer, you have to make sure that, first, you have enough dynamic range to represent the mix of your signal or do a division by $2$ to be on the safe side (although this is not the “true” mixed signal) and, second, that the conversions from and to any intermediate representations of your signals are done properly. I can’t be entirely sure that this is the problem you are facing here, but it feels like it should be related to that.

If possible I prefer to work with floating point audio. That is simply less hassle. Best if you can capture and playout floating point as well.
An audio mixer has to perform something like:
Out[n] = (in1[n] + in2[n]) /2
If you want to ensure that no distortion occurs, provided that input and output formats have the same numerical representation (and interpretation).
For fixed-point numbers, you may have to consider that the division operator usually is not rounding (add a bias) and think about intermediate precision.

division by 2, however, is safe, because unless you're already at minimum exponent, it retains the mantissa unchanged and reduces the exponent by one
